# Separar um datraframe em subdatraframes baseados em uma condição

Tags: r, loop

Gostaria de gerar subconjuntos de um dataframe via laço. Porém ao executar este código não obtenho os 5 objetos.

```
list <- list("CO", "N", "NE", "S", "SE")


for (i in list) {
   df_name <- paste("Regiao_",i)
   df <- df_AI[df_AI$Regiao == i,]
   df[[df_name]]<- df
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil é em uma linha de código.

```
list2env(split(df_AI, df_AI$Regiao), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

O `split` cria uma lista com um dataframe por cada valor único de `df_AI$Regiao`. E `list2env` transforma os elementos da lista em objetos no `environment` especificado.

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi direito sua questão, você quer criar um objeto para cada subset do data.frame df_AI. Se é esse o caso, pode usar a função `assign`:

```
df_AI <- data.frame(Regiao = c("CO", "N", "NE", "S", "SE"),
                    numero = 1:5)

for (i in unique(df_AI$Regiao)) {
  assign(paste0("Regiao_", i), df_AI[df_AI$Regiao == i, ])
}

> objects()
[1] "df_AI"     "i"         "Regiao_CO" "Regiao_N"  "Regiao_NE" "Regiao_S" 
[7] "Regiao_SE"

> Regiao_CO
  Regiao numero
1     CO      1
```

Comment: Perfeito Carlos, era exatamente isso! Muito obrigada. 

Apenas uma dúvida adicional. Qual a diferença entre o paste0 e o paste (usando o sep ="") ?

Comment: Nenhuma, `paste0` é só um atalho.

Comment: Considere [a resposta do Rui Barradas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/419141/117168), ela é mais prática (entre outras coisas, por descartar o uso de loop).